# mouting "t.bin"

Tags: mount

I have this file that I got from a friend who says that its the disk image of an android mobile. Doing a `file` on the image I get the following:-

```
$ file t.bin 
t.bin: Linux rev 0.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=badcafee-dead-beef-0000-000000000000
```

So I try to mount this onto a folder in order to see its contents:-

```
$ mkdir testmountpoint
$ cd testmountpoint
$ sudo mount t.bin testmountpoint/
mount: /home/developer/analysis/data.bin is not a block device (maybe try `-o loop'?)
$ sudo mount -o loop t.bin testmountpoint/
mount: Stale NFS file handle
```

How could I go about reading the contents of this disk image?

Comment: `file` says "mounted or unclean", try to fsck it before mounting.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some information missing from your question, namely how NFS is being used on your system.

**Is the file system image stored on an NFS mounted file system?**

If so, try copying it to a local file system and then mount it.  For example:

```
cp t.bin /tmp
sudo mount -o loop /tmp/t.bin testmountpoint/
```

If that still doesn't work, try the next option:

**If NFS is not being used on your system**

Perhaps there is some inconsistency in the file system image.  Try running `e2fsck` on the image to clean things up.  If the image is precious, I would recommend taking a backup of it first.

```
e2fsck t.bin
sudo mount -o loop t.bin testmountpoint/
```